# В каком предложении допущена пунктуационная ошибка ?

Tags: языкознание

1) Вышедший рано утром отряд до города ещё не добрался.
2) Озаряемые сиянием луны палатки казались серебристыми.
3) Кроме письма он получил и телеграмму.
4) Девушка стояла опустив голову.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Формально - ни в одном. 
Но как минимум в двух случаях не будет ошибкой и обособление. 
В примере 4) запятая наиболее вероятна. Здесь есть признаки наречного значения (обстоятельство образа действия), но развернутые обороты (с *неодиночным* деепричастием) обычно обособляются независимо от их роли в предложении.

//---------------

Поскольку вопрос ЭГЕшного типа не хочу брать грех на душу. 
Я знаю, что Людмила такие вещи знает лучше. И хотя я внутренне не согласен (или "не до конца согласен") с обоснованием, признаю её авторитет. А она рассудила в пользу ответа от [[@Виктор1799](/users/895/%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%BA%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%801799)](/users/895/%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%BA%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%801799).

Comment: Вы не совсем правы.Здесь действительно наречное значение, как в примерах: Мы ехали не спеша (нельзя: мы ехали и не спешили);  Он ходил согнув спину(нельзя: он ходил и согнул спину).
Такие  деепричастия и (реже ) деепричастные обороты сливаются со сказуемым в одно целое, не отделяются от сказуемого паузой и чаще всего стоят сразу после сказуемого: ходил наклонив голову, писал склонив голову, стояла опустив голову. Их можно заменить существительными с предлогами : с опущенной головой .Ошибка 2)причинное знач.- палатки казались серебристыми, т.к. озарялись сиянием луны.

Comment: >Вы не совсем правы.  
  
Это типа "немножко беременная"? Называйте уж своими именами, я серых тонов не понимаю. ) 
Но тут я бы возразил. Я бы ни в одном случае запятую не поставил, я гадал, где бы её таки поставить. Поэтому мне не интересно, что там в №4. А про №2 я бы поспорил. Можно  увидеть причинное значение. Но только как одно из возможных.  
Впрочем, я всегда исходил из этокой презумции невиновности. Если есть хоть малейшая возможность обосновать возможноть написать так, как написано, то ошибки нет.

Answer (score 1):

Я считаю, что это второе предложение. Причастный оборот "озаряемые сиянием луны" стоит перед определяемым словом "палатки", но у причастного оборота есть дополнительное причинное значение, поэтому нужна запятая.